# MariaDB 2.0.13 vs MySQL 5.3 ODBC Drivers (VBA Connection)

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

In Excel-VBA We used to have a sql database connection using MySQL drivers. Since this wasn't working for everyone we decided to install MariaDB drivers at every pc and use these drivers. The speed of opening an connection however, has decreased dramatically. Here is the code of the new and old vba script.

```
    p_dbConn.ConnectionString = _
          "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 2.0 Driver};" & _
          "SERVER=xx;" & _
          "DATABASE=xx;" & _
          "UID=xx;PASSWORD=xx;OPTION=3"
    p_dbConn.Open

    p_dbConn.ConnectionString = _
          "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};" & _
          "SERVER=xx;" & _
          "DATABASE=xx;" & _
          "UID=xx;PASSWORD=xx;OPTION=3"
    p_dbConn.Open
```

I ran the script in debug mode and the .open statement takes way longer with the mariadb driver. Anyone has any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not the driver that you are using ... but I use the following connection in my VBA code to connect to SQL Servers:

Reference File: Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library

```
'*************************************
'* SQL Server database connection    *
'*************************************
    Dim db As ADODB.Connection
    Set db = New ADODB.Connection
    db.Open "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source = 192.168.0.10; Database = [your DB Name];User Id = xxxxxx; Password = xxxxxxxx"
```

if a command takes longer than 45 seconds to execute ... use this to extend the execution default time

```
db.CommandTimeout = 1200 '(1200/60 = 20 minutes)
```

Sample Simple Commands

```
Set rst = db.execute("Select * from [your table name]")
db.execute("Delete from [your table name] where [your criteria]")
```

Comment: Connection is quick and the code is used on many PC's and laptops on a daily basis.